# ionic 2 deploying changes to Xcode build

Tags: xcode, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 to make an iOS app.

The issue is that the changes made in the projects are not deployed in Xcode build until I run the command `ionic build ios`, so I have to run this command for every single change, which is very time consuming.

I have tried `ionic prepare` but this does not work in ionic 2.

Is there an alternative I can use to save time?

Comment: Improved grammar and structure

Comment: ionic run ios works for me. Even ionic deploy. It builds and runs the project.

Comment: @milesper thank u so much